# Selecting conditional queries from a sub query MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to SELECT some values with WHERE conditions from a subquery.
I have some visit data for shops around the UK. Each shop is tied to a "venue" which is a "town/city/village" in the UK.
The subquery (temp_2) selects the correct data, the total visits for each shop in each venue. I now want to select the...

Average for a specific venue (your_visits)
National Average             (avg_visits)
Category visits, which is venues of the same category "town/city/village etc" (cat_visits)

From the temp_2 results set

I get the error temp_2 doesnt not exist, so is there another way to select results from this results set?

```
SELECT  name as name,
        (SELECT SUM(visits) FROM temp_2 WHERE venue_id = 4)      as your_visits,
        AVG(visits)                                             as avg_visits,
        (SELECT AVG(visits) FROM temp_2 WHERE category_id = 1)  as cat_visits
FROM (
        SELECT  MAX(gdsv.gps_data_customer_journey_activity_id) as gps_id,
                gdsv.name                                       as name,
                SUM(gdsv.visits)                                as visits,
                MAX(v.id)                                       as venue_id,
                MAX(v.category_id)                              as category_id,
                v.id                                            as venue_id
        FROM gps_data_shop_visits gdsv
            JOIN gps_data_customer_journey_activity gdcja on gdsv.gps_data_customer_journey_activity_id = gdcja.id
            JOIN event_area ea on gdcja.eventarea_name = ea.eventarea_name
            JOIN venue_gps vg on ea.venue_gps_id = vg.id
            JOIN venue v on vg.venue_id = v.id
        GROUP BY v.id, gdsv.name
         ) AS temp_2
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: You could put `temp_2` in [a temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) and mostly keep the same query. However this feature is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.13...

Comment: You could simply put the `WHERE` condition in your subquery, so the table that you create only contains rows with `venue_id = 4` and `category_id = 1`.

Comment: Can you share source tables' structure including sample data and tabulated expected results.

Comment: Thanks for getting back KIKO, however, I want the avg_visits, cat_visits and your_visits which would not be possible with your second comment suggestion as all other rows will be excluded.
I have tried a temp table but I cannot select from it more than once in the subquery selects

Comment: Hi @nazim, is tha really nessicary as the structure of the table I am trying to select from (temp_2) is there. The query to select results for temp_2 works as expected

Comment: You could execute multiple queries, not just one. This would work with the temporary table and with the second suggestion I made.

Comment: But isn't that against the spirit of sql?

Comment: Have you tried to use [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)?

Comment: Yeah that would've been ideal but sadly my company uses 5.7. I came up with a solution using CASE statements and counts